# React Hooks, how to access mounted parentNode with ReactDom

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-dom, react-component

I am currently migrating my **react components to react hooks**, but struggle with one specific case which is **accessing the mounted DOM element**.

My component using `React.class` structure :

```
import { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class LineGraph extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.element = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).parentNode;
    }

    render() {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Now using react hooks, `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)` throw the following error :

> TypeError: react_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.findDOMNode(...) is null

Looking at [ReactDOM#findDOMNode](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode) documentation, I tried to **use a references** on a returned empty div but after few draw element variable become `null`.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export default function LineGraph () {

    let myRef = React.createRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        element = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(myRef.current).parentNode;
    }, []);

    return (
      <div ref={myRef}></div>
    );
}
```

**I am looking a clean way to access the DOM element in which my react code is injected/mounted.**

*Just for context, my goal is to inject svg content using d3 library, my code works well with components.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem **is the timing** of accessing the reference.

Try using [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook with a listener to `myRef` change, and read it when it has a valid value:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default function LineGraph() {
  const myRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (myRef.current) {
      console.log(myRef.current.parentNode)
    }
  }, [])

  return <div ref={myRef}></div>;
}
```

[image: Edit react-parent-node-hooks]

Comment: It's not the actual problem. The actual problem is with the empty dependencies array.

Comment: There are many problems in his code, there are variables that not even defined

Comment: I don't see any not defined variables.

Comment: Also, the problem is not the empty dep array, you should check it by yourself, the problem is the miss-use of the reference

Answer (score 0):

There are some minor issues with your code, you can make it work and simplify it at the same time.

1. Remove the findDomNode method

It's not required as you are already accessing a node through the ref so you can use the .parentNode property directly on the referenced DOM node.

2. Update Parent Node on each re-render

By removing the empty array from your useEffect method the component will access the parent node each time the parent Node updates. Thereby you always have access to the freshly updated parent node.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qyydtt

```js
export default function LineGraph () {
    const parentRef = React.createRef();
    let parent;

    useEffect(() => {
     parent = parentRef.current.parentNode
    });

    return (
      <div ref={parentRef}></div>
    );
}
```